# Is it possible to remove the password on new generations of Lenovo X1?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, tpm

I have lost the password for my setup. 
I set it up a few years ago and now I cannot recall it.
The supervisor password is not stored in an EEPROM so the usual tricks do not work. 
I think it is in a TPM chip.
Would it be possible to reprogram the chip or replace it to remove the password?

I understand I might lose some key in the TPM that is required to decrypt the data on my hard-drive but that is not a problem. I don't have a boot password and still access my data on the hard-drive and can make a backup copy of it before proceeding with resetting the TPM chip.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Lenovo Support Website](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht036206#super):

> A forgotten Supervisor password will prevent access to the ThinkPad
>   BIOS setup utility. If the Supervisor password has been forgotten and
>   cannot be made available to the service technician, there is no
>   service procedure to reset the password. The system board must be
>   replaced for a scheduled fee. Proof of purchase is required, and this
>   repair is not covered under the warranty.

So this leads me to believe that there is something soldered onto the board that is storing the supervisor password, possibly the TPM. However, I have not been able to find any evidence for this claim. The way to reset the Supervisor password from here is replacing the system board, either by yourself or through Lenovo.